# Matriz dinâmica em C#

Tags: c#, lista, matriz

Qual seria a melhor forma para criar uma matriz quadrada dinâmica ?

Uma matriz que vá aumentando linha e coluna a medida que for aparecendo elementos para ser inserido na matriz

Encontrei alguns comentários na internet falando que a melhor forma de fazer isso seria criando Listas de listas

```
List<List<int>> matriz= new List<List<int>>();
```

Estou com dificuldades para entender como preencher a matriz.

Comment: `Estou com dificuldades para entender.`? Quais as dificuldades! o que você fez aparentemente dá para fazer um matriz de qualquer tamanho (linha  e colunas) só que o controle e via código. Fiquei na duvida de um cenário?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Desculpe pela falta de informação, minha dificuldade está em preencher essa matriz

Comment: Queria te ajudar mas, não tem como. mas, vou deixar um link https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHRkGQ é uma matriz 4 x 4 mas, eu sei que é! e sei que programei assim, essa lista pode aumentar tanto para coluna e linha ... o controle é feito via código

Comment: Muito Obrigado de qualquer forma

Comment: Se tiver duvida pergunta ai

Answer (score 0):

Use Tuple:

```
Tuple<int, int, int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int, int, int>( 1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> matriz = new List<Tuple<int, int, int, int>>();
matriz.Add(tuple);
```

Comment: Truplas podem ser escritas como `List<(int, int, int, int)>` também.

Comment: Isto não permite crescer linhas e colunas.